# ValueChanges on FormGroup is fired onKeyUp and onBlur

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, valuechangelistener

My Reactive Angular Form should be submitted on Key Up if the form is valid.

I registerd a subscriber on `valueChanges` but it is called onKeyUp and onBlur of each input and the form is submitted twice. It seems that this is a known issue (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12540) and as a solution `distinctUntilChanged` is suggested.
Unfortunately is seems not to work in my case. The submit is fired immediately no matter what time I set and still fired twice.

```
this.myFormGroup.valueChanges
  .pipe(debounceTime(2000), distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe(() => {
    if (this.myFormGroup.valid) {
      this.submitForm();
    }
  });
```

Does someone have an idea what could be my mistake with `distinctUntilChanged`? Or is there another method to prevent `valueChanges` to be fired onKeyUp and onBlur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

distinctUntilChanged uses `===` comparison by default, object references must match , `myFormGroup` will emit an object in every change and these objects are not the same **reference**

try to add custom method to handle changes

```
distinctUntilChanged((p: any, n: any) => JSON.stringify(p) === JSON.stringify(n))
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rarozy)

[distinctUntilChanged](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html)

Comment: Works in my case. Thanks!